# JavaScript Safari - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Tags: javascript, safari, syntax-error

I have the problem that this JavaScript snippet runs in Firefox / Chrome without any problem, and Safari I get error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'".

Here's the code:

```
window.onclick = (test) => {
  const googleWindow = window.open();
  fakeAjax(response => {
    googleWindow.location.replace(`https://google.com?q=${response}`);
  });
};

function fakeAjax(callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback('example');
  }, 1);
}
```

I've googled and have already seen here in the forum, the problem there appears often, unfortunately I have not found a suitable solution.

Thank you in advance
Best regards

Comment: look for the compatibilty mode of Javascript 6 or ECMAScript6 the syntax you are using belongs to higher version of js so check for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrow function ()=>{} is es6 feature, firefox and chrome both are already supported. But safari old version doesn't. Please check http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ for more information.

Comment: But, what should be the solution?

Comment: Use ES5 in the browser

Answer (score 2):

Safari 5.1 is really bad !!!

Example it does not load with =>

```
var t=w.map(v => String.fromCharCode(v));
```

Replacement it will take charge

```
var t=w.map(function(v){return String.fromCharCode(v)});
```

To make a script work on all browsers, avoid,

1. The `=>` and prefer `function () {}` instead
2. The `function (param = x) {}`, prefer `function (param) {if (param == 'undefined') {param = x;}}`
3. The `let` and use `var` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the arrow function syntax from es6 as Jerry Zhu already mentioned.

To support older browsers you need to replace "response => {" with "function(response) {" and also "setTimeout(() => {" with "setTimeout(function() {".

Answer (score 0):

Advice for you to be quiet with all browsers ...

1. Avoid using the `VAR => RESULT VAR`, prefer `function (VAR) {return RESULT VAR;}`
2. Never use parameters in your codes with values ​​like: `function (VAR = DEFAULTVALUE) {}`
   Use `function (VAR) {if (VAR == "undefined") VAR = DEFAULTVALUE;}`
3. To get an object: `document.getelementByID`
4. To specify an uninitialized property, choose `Object.setAttribute (property, value)` rather than `Object.property = value`. This can lead to errors or inappropriate behavior.

Some Styles properties can only be used if you set them up, especially the CSS3. Javascript accepts the same thing as CSS provided that you respect its usage.

5. to get DOM coordinates browsers from Netscape X and IE or other browser Opéra, FireFox, Apple X, etc...

`this.Ypos = document.body.scrollTop + ((! this.IE)? e.pageY: (window.event.y));
this.Xpos = document.body.scrollLeft + ((! this.IE)? e.pageX: (window.event.x));`
If coordinates smartphones Event page.X is : `Event.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length-1].pageX`;

6. To print an object in document: `Object.appendChild (mebox)`

I'm 53 years old, I've been working on the Internet for 35 years and since then nothing has really changed.