# Javascript and Jquery code is not loaded to Safari 9 or lower

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser

I guys, this is driving me crazy. I don't know why but my JS and Jquery scripts are not loaded on Safari 9, Safari 8 and lower. I don't really understand why.

I'm testing my codepen on all the browsers but I keep having this problem.

Here my JS / Jquery code:

```
// Gradient buttons news    

    $('.news-btn-div').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('.news-btn-div').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    })


// News

function req1() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}
req1();

function req2() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req3() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req4() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}

function req5() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/5')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      var title = json.title;
      var body = json.body; 
      document.getElementById("newsTitle").innerHTML = title;
      document.getElementById("newsContent").innerHTML = body;
      document.getElementById("newsContent2").innerHTML = body;
    });
}



// Subrscription confirmation without Ajax

$('#newsletter-cf').submit(function () {
  var email = document.getElementById("contact-email").value;
  if(email)
  {

    $("#newsletter-cf").slideUp("slow");
    $("#message-sent").slideDown("slow");

  }

  return false;
});
```

This is what I added in the head in order to use Jquery:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

I don't know what to check at this stage

This is the error that I get in Consolle (Safari 9)

[image]

Any precious advice?

---

The error for the JS part seems to be realted to this piece of code:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
```

As I read in this question:

[JavaScript Safari - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008975/javascript-safari-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I shouldn't use => in old browser, any I idea how I could change it in order to make it work on old browers too?

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have put additional information to your post, the problem is much clearer.

in the following code you are using arrow functions `=>`

```
.then(response => response.json())
```

They are supported in safari since version 10. It cannot work in version 9. You have to rewrite these as classic functions:

```
.then(function(response){
    return response.json(); 
});
```

Note that the particularity of arrow functions is to preserve the value of `this`, so that a real equivalent would be:

```
var self = this;
.then(function(response){
    //use self instead of this inside
    return response.json();
});
```

Once these errors solved, you then can know if jQuery works or not (and know if you need to detect Safari version so that another jQuery version should be loaded).